# Oracle space quota exceeded for table 'users'

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, database-administration

I was wondering whether the space quota varies for every different table? Because I've two tables where they have same number of columns with same data types.
For table 1, I'm able to insert 102,000+ rows but for table 2, I'm only able to insert 12,000+ rows.
Why is this varied between these two tables?

Comment: I expect the space usage also includes indexes and the like.  Also, for many datatypes, the space used will depend on the sizes of the actual values.  (Wouldn't a 1000 character string would occupy more space than a 1 character string in a VARCHAR field?)

Comment: Yes, but I'm pushing same data to both tables of same schema.

Comment: Yes, but **your question** doesn't say that.  And there is the index issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering whether the space quota varies for every different table?

In Oracle, space quota within a tablespace is defined for a *user* (i.e. schema), *not* at the table or other object level. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/managing-security-for-oracle-database-users.html#GUID-62EEE321-01AF-4AF4-9210-A74476613A0A

> Yes, but I'm pushing same data to both tables of same schema.

You were able to insert 102K rows in one table because you inserted them *first*. The inserts on the second table exceeded your user's total limit on the tablespace and raised the error.

You will need to speak with your DBA to get a higher or unlimited quota assigned.